# How to pass form data to external API using POST request in django view function?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

How to pass form data to external API using POST request in Django view function?

My API does not get my form data.

@csrf_protect

```
def home_page(request):
context = {}
if request.method =='POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # form.save()
        resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_api/save_user/',params=request.POST).json()
        print(resp,' - type = ',type(resp))
        context = {'success_message':'User registered successfully..!'}
    else:
        context = {'error_message':'Invalid Form Inputs'}
form = UserForm() 
context.update({'form':form})
return render(request,'home/index.html',context)
```

My API

```
class UserAPI(APIView):
def post(self,request):
    serializer =  UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        resp = {'resp' : 'User saved successfully..!'}
        print('data saved \n\n\n\n\n\n')
    else:
        resp = {'resp' : 'Invalid data..!'}
        print(serializer.errors,'invalid data  \n\n\n\n\n\n')
    return Response(resp)
```

Output : {'first_name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'last_name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'phone': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'email': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'password': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]} invalid data

Answer (score 0):

```
resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_api/save_user/',data=request.POST).json()
```

I jut have to replace params with data